Whoopsie doodles
Can you please tell me how this onomatopoeia is used, and in which language register?
Is this the same as "patatras" in French?
I saw this on an error page on the Internet. It was reading as follows: 404 Whoopsiedoodles! We tried really hard but we could not find the page you are trying to reach.

Are you thinking of Whoops-a-daisy? It's baby-talk for when someone falls over or drops something. Not onomatopoeia, which is when the word imitates a natural sound.

Alternatively, Green's claims it means eccentric, and Urban Dictionary pooping one's pants (a similar accident to whoops-a-daisy). Merriam-Webster Wordplay covers many variants of Whoopsy/Upsa-Daisy Which meaning are you thinking of? Where did you hear it? Why do you think it's an onomatopoeia? What is patatras in French?

You-tube has a few children’s songs with something close. Just silliness, relatively rare.

I saw this on an error page on the Internet. It was reading as follows:
404
Whoopsiedoodles!
We tried really hard but we could not find the page you are trying to reach.

"Whoopsie-doodles" isn't onomatopoeic. It's one of many variations on "oops" and "whoops", such as:

whoopsie-doodle
whoops-a-daisy
whoopsy-daisy
oopsy-whoopsy

Each of these have spelling variations (e.g., the ending can vary between "-sie" and "-sy"). They're all highly informal and playful expressions, which verge into baby-talk. They serve as interjections calling attention to a mistake (whether one's own or, more humorously, someone else's), or as a noun meaning "mistake".
The context in which you saw this word, an HTTP 404 page, is no coincidence. A misguided attempt to make software error messages seem less intimidating, over the past 10 or 20 years, has led to increasingly, insultingly ridiculous and verbose messages for routine errors, which come off as if they're trying to pacify a temperamental infant. I see whimsical error messages everywhere, but nowhere are they more common than on 404 pages. The trend was famously parodied by Tim Sutton in a 2016 Tumblr post thus:

normal website: 404 error - page not found
garbage millenial website: golly gee willikers, looks like you’ve taken a wrong turn!!!! looks like our army of busy little worker bees must have filed the page you were looking for in the wrong filing cabinet!!!! mayhaps you could try looking at one of our other many pages? ?? i am sure you would find something else you would like instead?? SO sorry you did not find what you were looking for!! may the force be with you fellow geek! :3 :3 :3

This is part of a larger trend of infantilization in user-interface design: the desire to make interfaces more intuitive and immediately understandable, as in the switch from typing on command lines to clicking on icons, gradually gave way to a presumption that users are inattentive, ignorant, impatient, and highly emotional, so an interface must make the most common tasks as easy as possible to do, without particular concern for more unusual, idiosyncratic, or complex tasks.

Is this the same as "patatras" in French?

No, the English equivalent of that would be more like "wham", "pow", or "kerblam".

Wow! That's some strong opinion. Did a whimsical 404 page kill your parents? (Also: we certainly shouldn't enter into a debate on UX philosophies in the comment section of an ELL answer… But I might suggest that insofar as much of modern software is driven by $$, "inattentive, ignorant, impatient, and highly emotional" users are exactly what some interests want, because they're the most monetizeable.)

Also by the way, it might be worth noting that "whoopsiedoodles" is a much rarer variant than the ones involving "daisy." It doesn't even register on ngrams.

"Did a whimsical 404 page kill your parents?" — Yes, and the apology card they sent me made it even worse.

I associate '(wh)oops-a-daisy' specifically with losing one's balance or accidentally dropping something.

This answer could be improved by reducing or entirely removing the UX rant.

+1 for infantilization
